# An ethernet cable is not properly plugged in or might be broken

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, lan, ethernet

I am trying to enable LAN on my laptop, but I failed with some unknown error. When I tried to diagnose the connection it shows an error like **An ethernet cabe is not plugged in or might be broken.** I just dont understand what is the meaning of this, as I am not working with ethernet but I am using wireless. I want to connect my two computer using LAN then how it would be possible?
Thanks.

Comment: Ok.  It shows an error "like" what you put in bold.  How about editing your answer so you tell us **exactly** what error is shown?  Also, provide necessary details... you know, like the Operating System you are using, the make and model of Laptop, make and model of wireless router you are connecting to, etc.  You say you are trying to enable LAN, which is typically ethernet based... but then say you are using wireless.  You need to rethink what you have said here, and detail EXACTLY what you have already done, and what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright.  I just found your other question that had been closed.  https://superuser.com/questions/437955/how-to-set-up-a-wireless-lan-in-home

If we combine that question, with this one... the issue appears to be that you are expecting the wireless card in each laptop to also act like a router... in that they would broadcast some name that you would be able to see from the other laptop, and that you would just be able to connect them to each other.

You want to create an AD-HOC network.  Trust me.  That is what you are talking about.  What you are going to have to do is follow some specific instructions to make ONE of the laptop's wireless cards ready to be connected to by the other.  This is not preparation that you are going to apply to BOTH of the laptop wireless cards.

Of course, the exact steps you would follow depend on what Operating System you are using, and the hardware (make and model of laptop) that you have.

So, [here is an article about setting up an AD-HOC network with Windows XP](http://www.home-network-help.com/ad-hoc-wireless-network.html).

Here is an [article at Microsoft.com about setting up an AD-HOC network with Vista](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/set-up-a-computer-to-computer-ad-hoc-network).

Here is an [article at Microsoft.com about setting up an AD-HOC network with Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Set-up-a-computer-to-computer-ad-hoc-network).  Interesting place to find information regarding Windows, eh?

Now, I included all three of those, because even though Kyle Jones edited this question to include the Windows 7 tag, there is actually no evidence that this question deals with Windows 7.  Nothing that the OP said indicates the OS is Windows 7... so I don't know why Kyle would have added that tag... unless Kyle knows the OP personally, and is personally familiar with the hardware that the OP is talking about.

Comment: Thankyou sir for your answer, however another problem arises. I hope you wont mind answering that.